# Unable to ping other subnet through IPSEC tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec, fortigate

I'm configuring an S2S IPSEC VPN tunnel between two Fortigate firewalls.

The tunnel is up and running. Network topology:

[image: topology]

When I ping from the LAN interface, which is directly connected to the Fortigate, to the other LAN interface, which also connected to the other Fortigate, (192.168.1.1 --> 10.0.0.1) it works.

When I ping the host, there is no response (192.168.1.2 --> 10.0.0.2).

I performed a packet capture but I don't see a problem.

Capture snapshots On FW-A:

[image: FW-A capture]

Capture snapshots on FW-B:

[image: FW-B capture]

One thing I noticed is the icmp session changes to another one like the snapshots show, but I can't find solution for this problem.

NB: this tunnel was created with the wizard template, so there is no way to be any issue related to the policy or static route due to the ping from the in  192.168.1.1 to 10.0.0.1 will not be successful.
Also I tried creating a custom tunnel but that did not work.

help!

Comment: Please  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. And that will allow people willing to answer your question to also copy-and-paste your commands/settings/error messages into their answer. -  Second try to use a spell check and capital letters.

Comment: When diagnosing connectivity issues `ping`  is a simple low level check, but keep in mind that more and more hosts and (host based) firewalls block  ICMP and therefor hosts won't ever respond to ping requests. And a ping failure is thus not (always) a good indicator of real connectivity issues.

Comment: No config? That would help identify why it isn't working.

Comment: @Greg Askew
i have debug test and snifing also but all the test seems  correct and no thing is might to be incorrect and also this tunnel is created by the wizard template so If there is an issue with the rules or routing or policies issue, the ping between 192.168.1.1 and 10.0.0.1 will not succeed. Furthermore, based on the debug logs, when the packet reaches FW-A, it is processed and allowed on the FW-A to FW-B interface, which serves as the VPN interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need a route on each network to ensure the hosts know how to get to the network on the other side of the VPN.

Network A should use IP Address a.b.c.d to access Remote Network B

a.b.c.d would be the VPN endpoint on the local network.

The method and syntax to add routes depends on your OS, etc, but a basic command might look like this:

```
ip route add <destination> via <gateway> dev <interface>
```

So for your scenario it might be:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1
```

Comment: in owr case i don't thing that we need to add a route in the hosts because when i try to ping any addres the ping request will reatch the firewall and then then firewall will decide what to do (will forward it to the int ..)

Comment: In that case, my next thought is VPN Encryption Domain may not include the hosts. The Encryption Domain is basically defines which local hosts will participate in the VPN. I'm not sure Fortigate will use the same term for this. My apologies, I don't know Fortigate firewalls. I did find this support post that mentions IP Nat Pool. Are the hosts involved included in the IP Nat Pool? This IP Nat Pool seems like the same thing as Encryption Domain, but I am not sure. https://community.fortinet.com/t5/Support-Forum/VPN-to-Checkpoint-with-encryption-domain-outside-local-network/td-p/50073